# Splitting up unusual date & time column format in R

Tags: r, date, time, split, format

It's likely a trivial question, but I'm attempting to break date and time into their own variables on a GPS data frame containing 1.4 million rows. The timestamp fromat is:

`2015-11-19T03:27:56`

I've been able to extract the date without any trouble, but the 'T' is giving trouble when attempting to extract time. The following code:

```
sater001$utc_d <- as.Date(sater001$utc_time_stamp)
```

where 'sater001$utc_d' is my data frame, and 'utc_time_stamp' is the variable I wish to split, the date is extracted just fine.

But running:

```
sater001$utc_t <- format(as.POSIXlt(sater001$utc_time_stamp) ,format = "T%H:%M:%S")
```

Gives me a column filled with `T00:00:00` values.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `lubridate::ymd_hms('2015-11-19T03:27:56')` works fine. To extract the time, `format(lubridate::ymd_hms('2015-11-19T03:27:56'), '%T')` (or `%H:%M:%S`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to also include the `T` in the format

```
v2 <- as.POSIXct(v1, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
v2
#[1] "2015-11-19 03:27:56 IST"
```

Now, we can extract the `hms` portion

```
format(v2, "%H:%M:%S")
```

NOTE: We don't need any additional packages to get the expected result.

#### data

```
v1 <- "2015-11-19T03:27:56"
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I was able to convert the time into this suggested format prior to splitting the columns into separate data and time vars. Thank you for the help, friend. I really appreciate it.